# Remove shadow and gradient from this p5.js sketch

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js, generative-art

I'm trying to adapt [this sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/theruantan/sketches/JXsPUlYgi) for my own work but I can't seem to figure out how to make it such that the tiles are solid colours and each row does not have that shadow.

The gradients and shadows are controlled by row 116 to 123.

Answer (score 1):

To make each tile a solid color simply replace the call to `gradient()` with a call to `fill()` given the color you want and `rect(x, y, w, h)`.

```js
// P_1_2_3_03
//
// Generative Gestaltung – Creative Coding im Web
// ISBN: 978-3-87439-902-9, First Edition, Hermann Schmidt, Mainz, 2018
// Benedikt Groß, Hartmut Bohnacker, Julia Laub, Claudius Lazzeroni
// with contributions by Joey Lee and Niels Poldervaart
// Copyright 2018
//
// http://www.generative-gestaltung.de
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

var colorCount = 30;
var hueValues = [];
var saturationValues = [];
var brightnessValues = [];
var actRandomSeed = 0;
var alphaValue = 255;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100, 100);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  noLoop();
  background(0);
  randomSeed(actRandomSeed);

  // ------ colors ------
  // create palette
  for (var i = 0; i < colorCount; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      hueValues[i] = 0;
      saturationValues[i] = 0;
      brightnessValues[i] = random(100);
    } else {
      hueValues[i] = 0;
      saturationValues[i] = 0;
      brightnessValues[i] = 100;
    }
  }

  // ------ area tiling ------
  // count tiles
  var counter = 0;
  // row count and row height
  var rowCount = 6;
  var rowHeight = height / rowCount;

  // seperate each line in parts
  for (var i = rowCount; i >= 0; i--) {
    // how many fragments
    var partCount = i + 1;
    var parts = [];

    for (var ii = 0; ii < partCount; ii++) {
      // sub fragments or not?
      if (random() < 0.075) {
        // take care of big values
        var fragments = int(random(2, 20));
        partCount = partCount + fragments;
        for (var iii = 0; iii < fragments; iii++) {
          parts.push(random(2));
        }
      } else {
        parts.push(random(2, 20));
      }
    }

    // add all subparts
    var sumPartsTotal = 0;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < partCount; ii++) {
      sumPartsTotal += parts[ii];
    }

    // draw rects
    var sumPartsNow = 0;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < parts.length; ii++) {
      sumPartsNow += parts[ii];

      var x = map(sumPartsNow, 0, sumPartsTotal, 0, width);
      var y = rowHeight * i;
      var w = -map(parts[ii], 0, sumPartsTotal, 0, width);
      var h = rowHeight * 1.5;

      var index = counter % colorCount;
      var col1 = color(0);
      var col2 = color(hueValues[index], saturationValues[index], brightnessValues[index], alphaValue);
      // gradient(x, y, w, h, col1, col2);
      fill(col2);
      rect(x, y, w, h);

      counter++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```